# Failure in creation of feature class: Unable to create object class extension COM component

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-server, arcobjects

I am working with ArcGIS 10.5, installed on-premise, and are developing our feature class in .NET.

I have an issue with registering feature classes. We have created a Feature Class and registered the DLL through “ESRIRegAsm.exe”, and it appears in ArcCatalog:

Trigger appearing image

[image: Trigger appearing image]

But when I try to create the Feature Class, I get the following error:

> Failed to create feature class. Unable to create object class extension COM Component

[image: Failed to create feature class. Unable to create object class extension COM Component]

Which isn't very helpful, unfortunately.

The odd thing is, that we have another trigger registered on another Feature Class, that works as expected. And the new trigger is based on a copy of the old trigger's code (with changed GUID's).

The steps I have done so far:

1. I have tried to add the feature class to the component category using categories.exe.
2. Registered it using ESRIRegAsm.exe for both Desktop and Engine.
   Checked that there are .ecfg config files - and there are.
3. Checked that the CLSID's appear in the windows registry.

The essential parts of our trigger source-code can be found here: [here](https://community.esri.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/228905-1-208363/TriggerHugstindsatsFeatureClass.zip).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as we are stuck on this.

Comment: Your code is similar to the sample timestamper classextension.  However, in your `Init` method you are not calling InitNew the way Esri does. https://github.com/Esri/arcobjects-sdk-community-samples/blob/master/Net/Geodatabase/TimestampClassExtension/CSharp/TimestampClassExtension.cs#L97

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our issue was that our ID's were wrong in the code.
The ClassExtensionCLSID should return the same ID as TriggerExtension has.

Moreover, InstanceCLSID should always return 52353152-891A-11D0-BEC6-00805F7C4268, and should hence not get a new ID.